# ostringstream is an undefined type?

Tags: c++, string, stream, iostream, ostringstream

In my C++ project I'm trying to do this:

```
 std::ostringstream stream(std::ostringstream::out);
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::basic_ostringstream<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'
```

I'm already including iostream and ostream libraries so I'm not sure why it's treating ostringstream as undefined...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::ostringstream` is defined in `<sstream>`. `<iostream>` only contains a forward declaration and `<ostream>` does not help at all.